# T-SQL: How to return separate columns of data for different date ranges selected from same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to get customer spending data by range from the orders table, but the script seems to always combine all the tables rows per customer id regardless of however I try to specify date ranges.  Any guidance in how I can accomplish my goal here is very appreciated.

EX:

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
(
    idCustomer INT IDENTITY(100,1),
    name VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (idCustomer)
);

INSERT INTO customers 
VALUES ('Bob'), ('Barb');

CREATE TABLE orders 
(
    idOrder INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    idCustomer INT,
    orderTotal DECIMAL(19,2),
    orderDate DATETIME2
    PRIMARY KEY (idOrder)
);

INSERT INTO orders 
VALUES (100, 25.25, '2018-4-15'),
       (100, 37.00, '2018-6-15'),
       (100, 175.00, '2019-3-1'),
       (100, 232.33, '2019-8-3'),
       (101, 18.56, '2018-1-17'),
       (101, 3004.50, '2018-5-12'),
       (101, 2.98, '2019-6-1'),
       (101, 15.00, '2019-11-3')

SELECT
    c.idCustomer,
    c.name,
    COUNT(ord2018.idOrder) AS '#Orders 2018',
    SUM(ord2018.orderTotal) AS 'Total Spent 2018'
    COUNT(ord2019.idOrder) AS '#Orders 2019',
    SUM(ord2019.orderTotal) AS 'Total Spent 2019'
    COUNT(ordersAll.idOrder) AS '#Orders Lifetime',
    SUM(ordersAll.orderTotal) AS 'Total Spent Lifetime'
FROM 
    customers c
JOIN 
    orders ord2018 ON ord2018.idCustomer = c.idCustomer 
                   AND ord2018.orderDate > '2017-12-31'
                   AND ord2018.orderDate < '2019-1-1'
JOIN 
    orders ord2019 ON ord2019.idCustomer = c.idCustomer
                   AND ord2019.orderDate > '2018-12-31'
                   AND ord2019.orderDate < '2020-1-1'
JOIN
    orders ordersAll on ordersAll.idCustomer = c.idCustomer
GROUP BY 
    c.idCustomer, c.name
```

I want to see something like this:

| idCustomer | Name | #Orders 2018 | Total Spent 2018 | #Orders 2019 | Total Spent 2019 | #Orders Lifetime | Total Spent Lifetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Bob | 2 | 62.25 | 2 | 407.33 | 4 | 469.58 |
| 101 | Barb | 2 | 3023.06 | 2 | 17.98 | 4 | 3041.04 |

But I am getting duplicate values across the total columns which appear to just be the sum of all records in orders table per customer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag with the _version_ of SQL Server (`SELECT @@VERSION;`). Also, can you define in advance what years you care about? Or will you need it to always dynamically produce all of the years present in the table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks.  This is 2016 (tagged).  For now, I will need lifetime total data, 2021 data and 2022 data, all displayed separately.  This could be expanded to include 2020 and 2019 eventually.

Comment: Ok, that's a slightly different problem then, you didn't mention lifetime as a separate thing in the question, and your sample data is only 2018 and 2019?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes I failed to include that I would also want lifetime data in its own column.  Looks like I incorrectly perceived that as inconsequential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the defined problem and with the years you know about from the sample data hard-coded:

```
;WITH agg AS
(
  SELECT idCustomer, y = YEAR(orderDate), 
    OrderCount = COUNT(*), 
    TotalSpent = COALESCE(SUM(orderTotal),0)
  FROM dbo.orders
  GROUP BY idCustomer, DATEPART(YEAR, orderDate)
)
SELECT agg.idCustomer, c.name,
  OrderCount2018 = MAX(CASE WHEN y = 2018 THEN OrderCount END),
  TotalSpent2018 = MAX(CASE WHEN y = 2018 THEN TotalSpent END),
  OrderCount2019 = MAX(CASE WHEN y = 2019 THEN OrderCount END),
  TotalSpent2019 = MAX(CASE WHEN y = 2019 THEN TotalSpent END),
  LifetimeCount  = SUM(OrderCount),
  LifetimeSpent  = SUM(TotalSpent)
FROM agg
INNER JOIN dbo.customers AS c
  ON c.idCustomer = agg.idCustomer
GROUP BY agg.idCustomer, c.name;
```

However you want the query to be dynamic, so you can't be hard-coding years and column names. To do this dynamically:

```
DECLARE @MinYear int, @MaxYear int;

SELECT @MinYear = MIN(YEAR(orderDate)), @MaxYear = MAX(YEAR(orderDate))
  FROM dbo.orders;
  
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N';WITH agg AS
(
  SELECT idCustomer, y = YEAR(orderDate), 
    OrderCount = COUNT(*), 
    TotalSpent = COALESCE(SUM(orderTotal),0)
  FROM dbo.orders
  GROUP BY idCustomer, DATEPART(YEAR, orderDate)
)
SELECT agg.idCustomer, c.name';

;WITH y(y) AS (SELECT @MinYear UNION ALL
  SELECT y+1 FROM y WHERE y < @MaxYear),
  z(y) AS (SELECT CONVERT(char(4), y) FROM y)
 SELECT @sql += N',
  OrderCount' + y + N' = MAX(CASE WHEN y = ' + y + N' THEN OrderCount END),
  TotalSpent' + y + N' = MAX(CASE WHEN y = ' + y + N' THEN TotalSpent END)'
 FROM z;
  
SET @sql += N',
  LifetimeCount  = SUM(OrderCount),
  LifetimeSpent  = SUM(TotalSpent)
FROM agg
INNER JOIN dbo.customers AS c
  ON c.idCustomer = agg.idCustomer
GROUP BY agg.idCustomer, c.name;';

SELECT @sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output in both cases:

| idCustomer | name | OrderCount2018 | TotalSpent2018 | OrderCount2019 | TotalSpent2019 | LifetimeCount | LifetimeSpent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Bob | 2 | 62.25 | 2 | 407.33 | 4 | 469.58 |
| 101 | Barb | 2 | 3023.06 | 2 | 17.98 | 4 | 3041.04 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5eefe872ea58dc7f9a2be2c7118593dd)

Answer (score 3):

For your *supplied sample data* and considering your example query attempt, you can use a conditional sum in conjunction with *apply*.

```
select * 
from customers c
outer apply (
    select 
      IsNull(Sum(case when Year(orderdate) = 2018 then 1 end),0) [#Orders2018],
      IsNull(Sum(case when Year(orderdate) = 2018 then ordertotal end),0) [Total spent 2018],
      IsNull(Sum(case when Year(orderdate) = 2019 then 1 end),0) [#Orders2019],
      IsNull(Sum(case when Year(orderdate) = 2019 then ordertotal end),0) [Total spent 2019],
      Count(*) TotalOrders,
      Sum(Ordertotal) TotalSpend
    from orders o
    where o.idCustomer = c.idCustomer
)o;
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9db1564151274f9c21cebd9475563e53)

- Edit, added Totals for sake of completeness :)